# Storing encoded Features in the Feature Store?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, mlops

I am currently in the design phase of a feature store pipeline to train and serve ML models. One thing which confuses me is the "state" in which features are supposed to be stored in the feature store.

Let's assume I have a data source which has an entries of the following schema:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 0.1 | 20 |

During my data analysis I found that a feature *Value2 / Value1* is a meaningful feature for my ML model. This would yield:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 | V2_by_V1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 0.1 | 20 | 200 |

Now to the heart of my question: do I store this table in my feature store OR do I additionally apply transformations like scaling / binning / one hot encoding / ... and store the *encoded* features in the store?

A consultant from one of the big cloud providers opted for storing encoded features in the store which I find strange because different models will use the same type of feature but will need different encoding procedures and storing encoded value complicates model monitoring and debugging in production.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to reuse features in the feature store across multiple, you should not perform "model-specific transformations" on them (encoding categorical features, normalizing numerical features, etc).
Also, if your feature data in the feature store is mutable, again you shouldn't perform "model-specific transformations" - otherwise, every time you write to the feature table/group, you will potentially need to modify existing features in the group - e.g., re-normalize the numerical values (e.g., because the mean changed with the new data you wrote).

More details here:
https://youtu.be/BD1UOJs1Bvo?t=2426